# New lines are not permitted in crontab entries

Tags: cron, cpanel

I am trying to set a crontab in cPanel but it always show an error:

> New lines are not permitted in crontab entries.

Note: I am trying to do it from cPanel web interface.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a custom cPanel theme this may be caused due to an issue with a recent cPanel update which forces a security token. If you examine the url after hitting the submit button you should notice that the link is missing the security token (cpsess0000000000, for example).

In the past you could get around this by disabling the security token in WHM however this newest release by cPanel has prevented this from being disabled. I would recommend going back to the default theme(x3) and trying again.

I recently ran into this issue myself and am currently building a new cPanel interface for all  of my servers. I suppose that it's for the best though. I've been putting this on the back burner for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the contents in "/var/spool/cron/*username*"

it should be having a special character or a wrong format which is causing the issue from file being edited via the cPanel interface

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, once editing crontab using PHP script, I was no longer able to edit cron jobs from cPanel, and problem was in the windows/linux line breaks in the script:

```
shell_exec('echo "' . implode("\r\n", $array) . '" | crontab -');
```

So, replacing `\r\n` to `\n` fixed my issue.